# For loop no R está repetindo respostas mais vezes do que desejado

Tags: r, loop, for

Preciso de ajuda para este loop que está retornando mais respostas do que o desejado.

Fiz uma tabela a partir do dataset público `palmerpenguins` e o meu objetivo é obter uma estimativa do sexo dos pinguins com dados faltantes via comparação com o macho médio. A literatura diz que se o macho for 11% maior então x pode ser fêmea.

O primeiro loop que eu criei para esse efeito retorna mais respostas do que eu pretendo e eu não sei como arrumar. Fiz um segundo loop mais simples que retorna o numero de respostas desejadas, porém não faz referência ao número do pinguim.

O que estou fazendo errado no primeiro?

```
tabela_pinguins <- data.frame (

  numero_pinguim <- c(179,219,257,269,9,10,11,12,48),

  percentagem_da_diferenca <- c(24, 14, 13, 10, 13, -4, 17, 8, 25))

  for ( x in tabela_pinguins$percentagem_da_diferenca) {

    if(x > 11){
      numero_pinguim_femea <- which(tabela_pinguins$percentagem_da_diferenca> 11)
      mensagem1 <- paste("O pinguim", tabela_pinguins$numero_pinguim[numero_pinguim_femea], "é provavelmente uma fêmea.") 
      print(mensagem1)

    }else if (x<0){
   numero_pinguim_macho <- which(tabela_pinguins$percentagem_da_diferenca<0)
   mensagem2 <- paste("O pinguim", tabela_pinguins$numero_pinguim[numero_pinguim_macho], "é provavelmente um macho.") 
   print(mensagem2)

    } else {
   numero_pinguim_inconclusivo <- which(tabela_pinguins$percentagem_da_diferenca>0 & tabela_pinguins$percentagem<11)
   mensagem3 <- paste("Inconclusivo: O pinguim", tabela_pinguins$numero_pinguim[numero_pinguim_inconclusivo], "pode ser macho ou fêmea.")
   print(mensagem3)}
  }
```

Este loop retorna:

```
[1] "O pinguim 179 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 219 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
[3] "O pinguim 257 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 9 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  
[5] "O pinguim 11 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  "O pinguim 48 é provavelmente uma fêmea." 
[1] "O pinguim 179 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 219 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
[3] "O pinguim 257 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 9 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  
[5] "O pinguim 11 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  "O pinguim 48 é provavelmente uma fêmea." 
[1] "O pinguim 179 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 219 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
[3] "O pinguim 257 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 9 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  
[5] "O pinguim 11 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  "O pinguim 48 é provavelmente uma fêmea." 
[1] "Inconclusivo: O pinguim 269 pode ser macho ou fêmea."
[2] "Inconclusivo: O pinguim 12 pode ser macho ou fêmea." 
[1] "O pinguim 179 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 219 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
[3] "O pinguim 257 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 9 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  
[5] "O pinguim 11 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  "O pinguim 48 é provavelmente uma fêmea." 
[1] "O pingum 10 é provavelmente um macho."
[1] "O pinguim 179 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 219 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
[3] "O pinguim 257 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 9 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  
[5] "O pinguim 11 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  "O pinguim 48 é provavelmente uma fêmea." 
[1] "Inconclusivo: O pinguim 269 pode ser macho ou fêmea."
[2] "Inconclusivo: O pinguim 12 pode ser macho ou fêmea." 
[1] "O pinguim 179 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 219 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
[3] "O pinguim 257 é provavelmente uma fêmea." "O pinguim 9 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  
[5] "O pinguim 11 é provavelmente uma fêmea."  "O pinguim 48 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
```

Eu queria que o loop de cima retornasse o mesmo que este loop abaixo (a ordem está certa) mas com referencia ao numero do pinguim na resposta.

```
for(x in tabela_pinguins$percentagem_da_diferenca) {

  if(x>11) {
  print("O pinguim é provavelmente uma fêmea.")
} else if (x<0) {
  print("O pinguim é provavelmente um macho.")
} else {
    print("Inconclusivo: O pinguim pode ser macho ou fêmea.")}
  }
```

este retorna:

```
[1] "O pinguim é provavelmente uma fêmea."
[1] "O pinguim é provavelmente uma fêmea."
[1] "O pinguim é provavelmente uma fêmea."
[1] "Inconclusivo: O pinguim pode ser macho ou fêmea."
[1] "O pinguim é provavelmente uma fêmea."
[1] "O pinguim é provavelmente um macho."
[1] "O pinguim é provavelmente uma fêmea."
[1] "Inconclusivo: O pinguim pode ser macho ou fêmea."
[1] "O pinguim é provavelmente uma fêmea.
```

Comment: A estimativa é que o macho tem que ser APENAS 11% maior, ou MAIOR OU IGUAL a 11% ou  ATÉ 11% maior? Uma coisa é `estimativa = 11`, outra coisa é `estimativa >= 11` e outra coisa é `estimativa <= 11`.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta @solkarped!  Vc tem razão. a estimativa ficaria melhor se fosse >= 11. Já tentei essa alternativa mas não retornou a resposta desejada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do primeiro loop está nos trechos do código dados por

```
numero_pinguim_femea <- which(tabela_pinguins$percentagem_da_diferenca> 11)
numero_pinguim_macho <- which(tabela_pinguins$percentagem_da_diferenca<0)
numero_pinguim_inconclusivo <- which(tabela_pinguins$percentagem_da_diferenca>0 & tabela_pinguins$percentagem<11
```

Esses resultados são, respectivamente

```
numero_pinguim_femea
## [1] 1 2 3 5 7 9
numero_pinguim_macho
## [1] 6
numero_pinguim_inconclusivo
## [1] 4 8
```

Com isso, apenas o resultado do pinguim macho é único no primeiro output. Todos os outros apenas refletem o fato do número de pinguins fêmeas ou inconclusivos serem maiores do que 1.

Para resolver isso, é necessário que, para cada `x` em seu `for`, apenas um pinguim seja considerado com o `which`. Uma forma de fazer isso é adicionar um segundo contador `i` dentro do loop, que percorra os números dos pinguins e seja atualizado manualmente após os testes lógicos:

```r
i <- 1

for (x in tabela_pinguins$percentagem_da_diferenca){
  
  if(x > 11){
    numero_pinguim_femea <- tabela_pinguins$numero_pinguim[i]
    mensagem1 <- paste("O pinguim", numero_pinguim_femea, "é provavelmente uma fêmea.") 
    print(mensagem1)
    
  } else if (x < 0) {
    numero_pinguim_macho <- tabela_pinguins$numero_pinguim[i]
    mensagem2 <- paste("O pinguim", numero_pinguim_macho, "é provavelmente um macho.") 
    print(mensagem2)
    
  } else {
    numero_pinguim_inconclusivo <- tabela_pinguins$numero_pinguim[i]
    mensagem3 <- paste("Inconclusivo: O pinguim", numero_pinguim_inconclusivo, "pode ser macho ou fêmea.")
    print(mensagem3)}
  
  i <- i + 1
}

## [1] "O pinguim 179 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
## [1] "O pinguim 219 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
## [1] "O pinguim 257 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
## [1] "Inconclusivo: O pinguim 269 pode ser macho ou fêmea."
## [1] "O pinguim 9 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
## [1] "O pinguim 10 é provavelmente um macho."
## [1] "O pinguim 11 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
## [1] "Inconclusivo: O pinguim 12 pode ser macho ou fêmea."
## [1] "O pinguim 48 é provavelmente uma fêmea."
```

Comment: Muito obrigada @Marcus Nunes! Deu super certo! E valeu também por editar o meu post. Assim, me ensinou como fazer um post melhor para a próxima. ;)

Comment: Sem problemas : )